# Using regex to find email address and other values in Python String

Tags: python, regex, string, parsing

So I have a string that possesses data I need to extract for my main program.
It looks something like this:

```
string = "[email:first.last@gmail.com][days:90]"
```

From this string I want to extract the data within the brackets and be able to split email and the email address by the colon so that I can store the word email and the email address separately to get something like this:

```
string = "[email:first.last@gmail.com]"
... some regex here ...
param_type = "email"
param_value = "first.last@gmail.com"

if param_type == 'email':
   ... my code to send an email to param_value ...
```

The string could ultimately have at most 2 pairs of brackets for different parameter types so that I can specify what functions to handle:

```
string = "[email:first.last@gmail.com] [days:90]"
...regex to split by bracket group ....
param_type1 = "email"
param1 = "first.last@gmail.com"

param_type2 = "days"
param2 = "90"

if param_type1 != "":
   ... email code ...
if param_type2 != "":
   ... run other code for the specified number of days ...
```

The main program already has default values for these 2 param_types, but I want there to be the option to specify the email address, days, both, or neither.  If anything, I mainly need to know how to retrieve the email address as the online examples don't work for my situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use

```
\[([^:]*):([^\]]*)]*\]
```

That regular expression matches any [attribute:value] substring, with subexpression for the attribute and the value part.

It searches for a `[`, then for a few chars that are not `:`, then for a `:`, then for a few chars that are not `]`, then for a `]`.
And it encloses the part between `[` and `:` and the one between `:` and `]` into parenthesis.

So that if you use `findall` on this regex, it returns a list of all pairs `[attribute:value]` found in the string.

Example:

```py
import re

string = "[email:first.last@gmail.com] [days:90]"
pairs=re.findall(r'\[([^:]*):([^\]]*)]*\]', s)
# pairs = [('email', 'first.last@gmail.com'), ('days', '90')]
for attr,val in pairs:
    if attr=='email':
        doSomethingWithEmail(val)
    elif attr=='days':
        doSomethingWidhDays(val)
```

Comment: Oh my god that is so elegant.  All the answers online had regex strings that were way too long to understand and that wasn't reasonable for maintaining the program.  You are a life saver!

Answer (score 1):

So, in this case, you can just use a regex to extract what is between the brackets, then split on a colon character to get the param type and param, something like:

```
[s.split(":") for s in re.findall(r"\[(.+?)\]", string)]
```

So your code would be something like:

```
import re

string = "[email:first.last@gmail.com][days:90]"
type_and_param_pairs = [s.split(":") for s in re.findall(r"\[(.+?)\]", string)]
for param_type, param in type_and_param_pairs:
    if param_type == "email":
        # do something
    elif param_type == "days":
        # do something else
    ...
```